# How to add and atribute to the json reponse coming from my server

Tags: java, spring

So I have a REST controller and I'm trying to catch the message coming from the IllegalStateException

```
  @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getAllStudent(){

    throw   new IllegalStateException("Opps can not get all students");
      //return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }
```

In my front end I want to log the message "Opps can not get all students" When I use Postman I get this JSON response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-08-29T22:06:47.477+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/students"
}
```

How do I add a message attribute to the JSON so I can use it in my front end?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) you mmight need to configure a global exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception as you like (`YourselfException`) such as *"Can not get all students Exception"*
then you can define a `GlobalExceptionHandler` and you can return the message you want

For more information, you can try search `"GlobalExceptionHandler"`

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = YourselfException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public Response bizExceptionHandler(YourselfException e){
        return Response.fail(e.getMessage);
    }
}
```